# Не до конца пишет в файл

Tags: c#, filestream

Функция пишет в файл html код. 
Но последней строчкой в файле является `<br></td></tr><tr><td>Источники`
При отладке все строки программы проходит без ошибок.

```
            FileStream file1 = new FileStream(Application.StartupPath + "\\perort.html", FileMode.Create);
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(file1, Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8"));
        writer.Write("<html> <head><title>Подробный отчет</title><style type = \"text/css\" media = \"screen\">" +
            "body{ padding: 0px; margin: 0px;} #page{ height: auto; background-color: #edf0ee; padding-top: 1%;" +
            " } #content{ height: 100%; background-color: #fff; margin-right: 10%; margin-left: 10%; padding-top: 10px;"+
            " } #img{ float: left; width: auto; height: 100%; display: inline; margin-left: 10%; margin-right: 5%;"+
            " } img{ width: 250px; height: auto; vertical-align: middle; } #right { width: auto; margin - right: 10px;"+
            " margin-top: 60px; display: inline; text-align: right; } </style></head><body><div id = \"page\">" +
            " <div id = \"content\"><div id = \"img\"><img src = \"" + DataForm.parData.crop_photo.photo.photo_604+
            "\"></div><div id = \"right\"><table><tr><td> Online: <br></td>");
        string res = isOnline();
        writer.Write("<td>" + res + "<br></td></tr><tr><td>Статус:<br></td>");
        writer.Write("<td>" + DataForm.parData.status + "<br></td></tr><tr><td>Фамилия:<br></td><td> ");
        writer.Write(DataForm.parData.first_name + "<br></td></tr><tr><td>Имя:<br></td><td> ");
        writer.Write(DataForm.parData.last_name + "<br></td></tr><tr><td>Дата рождения:<br></td><td>");
        try { res = DataForm.parData.bdate; } catch { res = ""; }
        writer.Write(res + "<br></td></tr><tr><td>Город:<br></td><td>");
        try { res = DataForm.parData.city.title; } catch { res = ""; }
        writer.Write( res + "<br></td></tr><tr><td>Пол:<br></td><td>");
        res = isSex();
        writer.Write(res + "<br></td></tr><tr><td>Семейное положение:<br></td><td>");
        res = isSP();
        writer.Write(res + "<br></td></tr><tr><td>Текущий род занятий:<br></td><td>");
        res = isOccupation();
        writer.Write(res + "<br></td></tr><tr><td>Номер телефона:<br></td><td>");
        try { res = DataForm.parData.contacts.mobile_phone; } catch { res = ""; }
        writer.Write( res + "<br></td></tr><tr><td> Количество фотоальбомов:<br></td>" +
            "<td>");
        try { res = DataForm.parData.counters.albums.ToString(); } catch { res = ""; }
        writer.Write(res + "<br></td></tr><tr><td>Количество видеозаписей:<br></td>" +
            "<td>");
        try { res = DataForm.parData.counters.videos.ToString(); } catch { res = ""; }
        writer.Write(res + "<br></td></tr><tr><td>Количество аудиозаписей:<br></td>" +
            "<td>");
        try { res = DataForm.parData.counters.audios.ToString(); } catch { res = ""; }
        writer.Write(res + "<br></td></tr><tr><td>Количество фотографий:<br></td>" +
            "<td>");
        try { res = DataForm.parData.counters.photos.ToString(); } catch { res = ""; }
        writer.Write(res + "<br></td></tr><tr><td>Количество заметок:<br></td><td>");
        try { res = DataForm.parData.counters.notes.ToString(); } catch { res = ""; }
        writer.Write( res + "<br></td></tr><tr><td>Количество друзей:<br></td><td>");
        try { res = DataForm.parData.counters.friends.ToString(); } catch { res = ""; }
        writer.Write( res + "<br></td></tr><tr><td>Количество сообществ:<br></td><td>");
        try { res = DataForm.parData.counters.groups.ToString(); } catch { res = ""; }
        writer.Write( res + "<br></td></tr><tr><td>Количество видеозаписей с пользователем:" +
            "<br></td><td>");
        try { res = DataForm.parData.counters.user_videos.ToString(); } catch { res = ""; }
        writer.Write(res + "<br></td></tr><tr><td>Количество подписчиков:<br></td>" +
            "<td>");
        try { res = DataForm.parData.counters.followers.ToString(); } catch { res = ""; }
        writer.Write(res + "<br></td></tr><tr><td>Количество интересных страниц:<br>" +
            "</td><td>");
        try { res = DataForm.parData.counters.pages.ToString(); } catch { res = ""; }
        writer.Write(res + "<br></td></tr><tr><td>О себе: <br></td><td>");
        try { res = DataForm.parData.about; } catch { res = ""; }
        writer.Write(res + "<br></td></tr><tr><td>Политические предпочтения:<br></td><td>");
        res = isPolitical();
        writer.Write(res + "<br></td></tr><tr><td>Мировозрение: <br></td><td>");
        try { res = DataForm.parData.personal.religion; } catch { res = ""; }
        writer.Write(res + "<br></td></tr><tr><td>Источники вдохновения: <br></td>" +
            "<td>");
        try { res = DataForm.parData.personal.inspired_by; } catch { res = ""; }
        writer.Write(res + "<br></td></tr><tr><td> Главное в людях: <br></td><td>");
        res = isPeople();
        writer.Write(res + "<br></td></tr><tr><td>Главное в жизни: <br></td><td>");
        res = isLife();
        writer.Write(res + "<br></td></tr><tr><td>Отношение к курению: <br></td><td>");
        res = isSmoking();
        writer.Write(res + "<br></td></tr><tr><td>Отношение к алкоголю: <br></td><td>");
        res = isAlcohol();
        writer.Write(res + "<br></td></tr><tr><td> Любимые цитаты:<br></td><td>");
        try { res = DataForm.parData.quotes; } catch { res = ""; }
        writer.Write(res + "<br></td></tr><tr><td>Верифицирована:<br></td><td>");
        if (DataForm.parData.verified == 1) res = "Да";
        else res = "Нет";
        writer.Write(res + "<br></td></tr><tr><td>Режим стены:<br></td><td>");
        if (DataForm.parData.wall_default == "owner") res = "Только для владельца";
        else res = "Для всех";
        writer.Write(res + "<br></td></tr></table>");
        writer.Write("</div></div></body></html>");
        file1.Close();
```

Comment: О_О Новая парадигма: трай-кетчевая.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.flush(v=vs.110).aspx

```
...
writer.Write("</div></div></body></html>");
writer.Flush(); // Вот это.
file1.Close();
```